# How to structure repeated measures in GLM based on my study design? Nested or not nested

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, nested-data

So I'm having some trouble deciding how to format the repeated measures in my model. Basically deciding between:

```
Glm1<- glmmTMB(InsectAttacks ~ Treatment + Week + (1|Tree), family = nbinom2) 


Glm2 <- glmmTMB(BeetleAttacks ~ Treatment + Week + (1|Tree/Log), family = nbinom2)
```

I'm testing the efficacy of an insect repellent for its ability to deter insect attack on trees.

There are three treatments (Repellent1, Repellent2, and Control).

Each replicate is made up of 3 trees so there is one tree with each treatment per replicate.

Where it gets a bit confusing is that each tree was cut down and sectioned into 5 logs and placed in a pile. The pile of logs is the unit that the treatments were applied to. Each of the 5 logs per pile were counted separately for new insect attacks each week.

In this way I am subsampling each tree 5 times I think.

So would the correct format to indicate this in my model be (1|Tree) or the nested format (1|Tree/Log).

Answer (score 5):

From the description of your study design, you appear to have a hierarchical/nested structure, where each of 5 `Log`s "belong" to one and only one `Tree`. Thus, the random structure should be:

```
(1 | Tree/Log)
```

In order to avoid confusion, ensure that each `Log` is coded uniquely, so logs 1-5 belong to tree 1, logs 6-10 belong to tree 2 and so on.

You should also consider whether the default residual error structure (compound symmetry I believe) in glmmTMB is appropriate for your study. Since you have repeated measures, this may induce autocorrelation where correlations between the observations closest in time are stronger than those that are further away. This can often be modelled with an AR(1) structure. I would also advise considering an unstructured covariance matrix where no structure is imposed and the software estimates individual covariances between the all time points.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! So the unstructured covariance matrix would possibly be a more appropriate alternative to the compound symmetry inherent in a glmmTMB? Do you know how I would indicate that in my model? I'm trying to figure it out now but am somewhat new to this.

Comment: You're welcome. For an unstructured covariance matrix, I think you can use the `us()` function in `glmmTMB`, with the syntax this syntax:  `...+ us(week + 0 | Tree/Log) + ...` but please bear in mind that the software has to estimate many more covariances estimates than with compound symmetry or AR(1). See [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html#the-unstructured-covariance) for further details, and `week` will need to be coded as a factor variable.